# .htaccess misconfiguration issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using 1and1 as a web host and I was told that to enable the https for my website, I need to add the following lines to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\ooples.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ooples.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I currently have my website destination set to the webspace folder /Ooples and this is what my current .htaccess file looks like after I made the changes:

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

RewriteBase /Ooples
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\ooples.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ooples.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is my first time editing the .htaccess file and when I go to my website, I get a 500 internal server error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That rule is wrong, and enabling https can not be done by editing .htaaccess

Answer (score 0):

If indeed they have installed a certificate for your domain, adding the .htaccess rules below will ensure all requests are served via https:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ooples\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ooples.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But bear in mind that it shouldn't cause a server error. Do check your server logs for the error.